# Extract text from uploaded pdf and store it in a database

Tags: pdf, html, php, mysql

I have an HTML form where a user can upload a PDF.
I want to extract the whole text from the PDF, search in it for specific words and then store them in my database. Any ideas?
I don't ask you for the whole code of course, but something to begin with. Like a library or something like OCR, but free.

Comment: i work in php . that's why i use that tags

Comment: Not sure if this is an option in your scenario, but consider distributing *fillable PDFs* beforehand and then you can easily extract structured data from it.

Comment: Why are you thinking of OCR? Aren't these PDFs text?

Answer (score 0):

If the pdf has been created programmatically, *rather than scanned,* the python library [pdfminer](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfminer/) can extract the text for you.

It and python are free, gratis & open source, and are available for most platforms.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I am afraid that the pdf it's scanned plus i don't know much about Python ! I work mostly in java , c++ , php , html .

Comment: The problem with scanned pdf files is that basically they are images, with possibly some attempt at OCR. You could look at https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract for an Apache Licenced OCR it is C but there are wrappers for python, java and a few others.

Answer (score 0):

What about [this S.O question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14284656/free-ocr-processing-api-in-php-jquery-javascript) ?

The article [OCR in PHP: Read Text from Images with Tesseract](https://www.sitepoint.com/ocr-in-php-read-text-from-images-with-tesseract/) explains more.

There is a [PhpOcr project](https://phpocr.sourceforge.net/) on SourceForge.

[Tesseract](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract) would seem to be your best bet.